# Is regular expression in ngPattern different from the common regex?

Tags: regex, angularjs

Just want to know if the regex in `ng-pattern` is different from common regex.

Example:

For a zip code,

```
ng-pattern="/\d{5}(?:[-]\d{4})?/"
```

I also tried

```
ng-pattern="/(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)/"
```

A zip code like `12345-5` will pass the validation.

My grouping `(?:   )` appears ineffective. What could be wrong?

Comment: I am just curious why an invalid zip code can pass the pattern check.

Comment: It matches because you haven't anchor the regex.

Comment: I got it. Thanks! anchor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-capturing group (?: ) can have zero captures.
So you get a match for the first \d{5}, which is not null, which means you have a match.

I recommend https://www.regex101.com/, plus you can try your test in your browser console, just type for example

```
"12345-6".match(/\d{5}(?:[-]\d{4})?/)
```